# Missing libiconv-2.dll error when compiling on Notepad ++

Tags: dll, mingw, notepad++

I recently started using Notepad++  for programming. Now i get an error reporting that the libiconv-2.dll is missing. This happens when ever I try to compile using MinGW (which i just installed). 
 I have checked and the DLL is in the bin folder of MinGW. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the directory that storage libiconv-2.dll in your $PATH?

Comment: Well it was not. However, adding it did not help. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Update. Now i have added the MinGW folders to the path and it is missing  other DLLs in addition to the original issue.

Comment: What MinGW folders did you add to $PATH?

Comment: Only the mains folder (c:\minGW) and the bin (c:\minGW\bin)

Comment: BTW: Where did you get your mingw distribution? What other dlls are you missing? How did you add them in your $PATH?

Comment: I downloaded from the MinGW website. i added them through the windows advanced settings ("My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" ) I think that is what that is called, i have my OS in another language. And, finally the DLLs are: libmpfr-4, libgmp-10, libiconv-2 and libmpc-3.

Comment: ok, so far so good. And do you have those dlls somewhere in your drive? If so, add their directories to $PATH. Basically that simple.

Comment: All of those DLLs can be found in the c:\MinGW\bin directory, which is on the $PATH. That is what drives me nuts.

Comment: go to bin folder in cmd and compile your code.

Comment: i have reached that solution, however the compiled file then requires the dlls to run

Comment: have you compiled your cpp file? for using exe file you need to copy dll near exe file.